# Blackberry Cascades SystemDialog theme

Tags: dialog, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I'm using [this](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/ui/dialogs_toasts/system_dialogs.html)  manual to create ok/cancel modal dialog box in my Blackberry 10 application.

I defined dialog in QML and called .show() method. The dialog works well, but it always uses **bright**(white) theme. Even if current theme set to **dark** and all other controls are dark - the dialog is always white.

Is there any way to make the dialog work as all others controls in application.

Here my QML fragment with dialog:

```
 SystemDialog {
    id: interruptDialog
    title: qsTr("title")
    body: qsTr("Do you really want to do this?")
    onFinished: {
       someAction();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SystemDialog` can't be themed. You'd have to make your own custom dialog if you want to change the look.

https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/ui/dialogs_toasts/custom_dialogs.html

Even on a Q10 device, where the OS-wide theme is dark, a `SystemDialog` would still show with a blue header and white body.

https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/ui/dialogs_toasts/system_dialogs.html

> A SystemDialog is a dialog box that is standardized across all applications. These dialog boxes have a predefined look and feel for BlackBerry 10.